# can't draw image to canvas unless I use setInterval?

Tags: javascript

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#snake');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//create canvas unit
const box = 32;

//load image files
const ground = new Image();
ground.src = 'img/ground.png';
const food = new Image();
food.src = 'img/food.png';

//load audio files
let dead = new Audio();
let eat = new Audio();
let up = new Audio();
let down = new Audio();
let left = new Audio();
let right = new Audio();

dead.src = 'audio/dead.mp3';
eat.src = 'audio/eat.mp3';
left.src = 'audio/left.mp3';
up.src = 'audio/up.mp3';
down.src = 'audio/down.mp3';
right.src = 'audio/right.mp3';

//create snake

let snake = [];

//draw canvas
ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0)
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="snake" width="608" height="608"></canvas>
```

I'm following a tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TcU2C1AACw&t=190s) on how to make a snake game with javascript. I copied his code and commented it out. Now I'm reconstructing it piece by piece to see how it works, but not step by step.

For instance once i created the global variables i wanted to draw the background image to the canvas just to look at it `ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);` this by itself doesn't work. Watching him do it in the video he creates a draw function, puts that code in it, then sets the function to run at an interval of 100ms.

```
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);
}

let game = setInterval(draw, 100);
```

Now it works?? what's happening?

here's his github https://github.com/CodeExplainedRepo/Snake-JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to SO! Though you have not shared much of code, the way you explains it, its because the element is not rendered. Try putting script tag at the end or put your code in `window.load = function() { // your code } `

Comment: @Rajesh putting the script tag below the body still doesn't work. using window.onload does work though, can you tell me what's going on under the hood or link something that i can read up on cause i still don't understand the main issue. I am aware that the body is loaded before the JS is but even then shouldn't that just delay the image from appearing? cause when i put the script tag below the body or leave it in the body like i originally had it, it wasn't appearing at all?

Comment: Please try to keep code as minimal as possible. I have updated the code and removed any unwanted/ commented code

Comment: Also to answer, its not about images. when you put your code in `window.load`, it will wait until HTML has rendered. So your script gets any element its trying to access. Putting it directly will execute it as and when its read. So you are trying to access an element that is not available

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, thanks for the help:)

Comment: @Rajesh wait but my script tag is below the body tag and that doesn't work? shouldn't the canvas tag be loaded by then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm know i'm late. I was asking myself the same question after seeing that tutorial...

But still, you can pass this problem by simply adding the property `background-image` :

```
canvas id="snakeCanvas" width="608" height="608" style="background-image: url(img/ground.png)"
```